# ARIMA versus a Mixed model for trend detection

Tags: r, time-series, arima, mixed-model

I am trying to find any evidence of warming in monthly times series data of water temperature over a 21-year period that is serially correlated. Essentially I am looking to determine a global trend, like what can be done with OLS regression with data that is from independent observations. I am at a crossroads in trying to determine whether a seasonal ARIMA model or a linear mixed model with a trend component as detailed by Crawley on page 799 of "The R Book" (2nd ed.) is the most appropriate method to use. I therefore explored both techniques, but got very contradicting answers!

ARIMA modelling gave me a seasonal ARIMA of form (2,0,2)(0,0,1)[12], indicating that no differencing is required and therefore that the series is stationary with NO trend.

However, the linear mixed affects modelling, comparing two models with and without a trend component using ANOVA and maximum likelihood indicated a highly significant trend (R notation):

```
model2: ave ~ sin(time * 2 * pi) + cos(time * 2 * pi) + (1 | factor(yr))

model1: ave ~ index + sin(time * 2 * pi) + cos(time * 2 * pi) + (1 | factor(yr))

ANOVA(model2,model1)

      Df  AIC     BIC     logLik deviance Chisq Chi Df Pr(>Chisq)   
model2 5 346.82   364.49    -168.41   336.82                           
model1 6 338.54   359.74    -163.27   326.54 10.28      1   0.001345 **
```

How can this be? What am I missing? Is it about assuming whether the trend is a parametric form (appropriate for linear mixed model) or whatever weird shape (appropriate for ARIMA)? If so how do I go about choosing which approach to adopt?

Thank you kindly for any advice.

Comment: Consider adding "R" as a flag of your question.

Comment: How did you get the (S)ARIMA model? Did you use the function `auto.arima` from the "forecast" package? If you expect the data to have a deterministic linear time trend rather than a stochastic trend, then a (S)ARIMA model need not be apropriate. Also, no wonder that you get the integration order of zero; while you would expect order 1 if there was a stochastic trend, it is still order 0 for a deterministic trend. Instead of (S)ARIMA via `auto.arima` you could consider comparing an ARIMAX model with monthly dummies and with/without a linear time trend as exogenous regressors.

Comment: Then compare the AIC and/or BIC values for the two models to see which model is closer to the "truth". Perhaps then the result will be similar to the one you get using the linear mixed model.

Comment: Dear Richard, apologies for the late reply (very); I experienced a tragedy in my life shortly after my post. I experimented a bit with auto.arima but found that the model it choose did not give reasonable ACF and PACF residuals. Therefore I used arima and did it manually trying to minimise AICc with different models. I think the issue boils down to ones philosophical approach as you have indicated previously. I have now tried you suggested (arimax) with monthly dummies as a linear trend with exogenous regresors and the trend was significant.

Comment: So if I assume that the series is derived from deterministic process I get a significant trend value. However, is I assume that the data are drive by a stochastic process I do not get an indication that there is a need to include a trend component in the model. I think the later approach makes the most sense to me as its based on the least assumptions..